# What can impact the speed of tests ran with Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

I got `Jest` working in my environment, but I'm fairly certain that it's running way slower than it's supposed to.

Currently, I'm just running 2 tests that are copied from the Jest intro tutorials. One is [a simple sum function](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html#content), and another is [a simple checkbox example using `Enzyme`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#dom-testing). They take on average about 10 seconds until they start running (showing `Determining test suites to run...` for that time), and then about another 10 seconds from that point onwards (once the timer starts). This seems absurdly long for such simple components...

I tried setting my `testEnvironment` to `node` to speed things up, but it hasn't made much of a difference.

So accordingly:

1) Is this normal?

2) If not - what can cause `Jest` to slow down like this?

**Some potential factors?**

1) I *am* running these tests within a larger `React` project that contains ~20 or so react components, but none of them are being referenced by any of the tests - so I don't think they should be impacting this. =/

2) I'm using the `fileName.test.js` naming system to let `Jest` know where the test files are, instead of putting everything in a `__tests__` folder as per the tutorials.

Comment: did you have success fixing this issue?

Comment: Not with this environment, no. But the next ReactJS project I worked on where I also used Jest did not have this issue. It was a much simpler project. I still don't understand what was wrong in the first environment - I believe it was a bug in Jest, and have seen on GitHub issues that many people have had the same problem.

Comment: have you tried https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting.html#tests-are-extremely-slow-on-docker-and-or-continuous-integration-ci-server or disabling `automock`?